# How to match newlines with Alex/Haskell

Tags: haskell, newline, alex

I borrowed the example presented here

http://www.haskell.org/alex/doc/html/introduction.html

I am trying to make an interpreter for numerical expressions. (literals only, no variables) And I want to have newlines separate two different expressions. Unfortunaltely, when I do this

$ignoredWhite = [\t\f\v\r]      -- ignored whitespace

$newline = "\n"             --new line

Alex (v 2.2) aborts compilation.  I have tried

$newline = \n               --new line

but that just causes the abort to move from alex to final binary (aka one generated by ghc), when it is reading the input.

How do I go about fixing this?

Answer (score 3):

This question is really old, nevertheless I'll post my answer for future visitors. When the tokens are defined, I tell alex to process all whitespace:

```
tokens :-
  $white {\p s -> checkWhite p $ head s}
```

`checkWhite` looks like this:

```
checkWhite :: AlexPosn -> Char -> Token
checkWhite p '\n' = TNewLine p
checkWhite p _ = TEmpty
```

As you can see, it outputs a special token when newline is encountered. To delete `TEmpty` from output, you can use `... filter (\= TEmpty) $ alexScanTokens ...`.

Answer (score 2):

Just a guess - have you tried including it in a character range?

```
$newline = [\n]
```